# i18next with i18next-node-fs-backend shows key instead of string

Tags: typescript, electron, i18next

In my translations.ts code file I have:

```
import i18next from 'i18next';
import Backend from 'i18next-node-fs-backend';
import path from 'path';

i18next.use(Backend).init({
    lng: "en",
    fallbackLng: "en",
    backend: {
        loadPath: path.join(__dirname, '/translations/{{lng}}_{{ns}}.json')
    }
});

export default i18next;
```

Then, in my main.ts file I have:

```
import { dialog ] from 'electron;
import i18next from './translations';

// If something particular happens I want to show a dialog, like so:
dialog.showErrorBox(i18next.t('error.error'), i18next.t('error.text'));
```

The dialog box shows, but the text it displays is literally "error.error" and "error.text" instead of the strings from the `en_translation.json` file.

I get no error message. I feel like I'm not loading i18next (or the backend module0 correctly, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I've looked at other similar questions on Stack Overflow, but none of those questions or answers solve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

i18next has the concept of `namespace` which allows you to split the app into "areas" of translations.

You need to specify the default namespace, otherwise, you need to specify it as part of the key (`i18next.t('translation:error.error')`).

```js
import i18next from 'i18next';
import Backend from 'i18next-node-fs-backend';
import path from 'path';

i18next.use(Backend).init({
  lng: 'en',
  fallbackLng: 'en',
  defaultNS: 'translation', // <---- this is your default NS
  backend: {
    loadPath: path.join(__dirname, '/translations/{{lng}}_{{ns}}.json'),
  },
});

export default i18next;
```